# Photoshop, duplicate layer order down (instead of up)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'm working with Photoshop for over 10 years already but can't find this simple thing:

When I'm creating repeatable objects I always duplicate folders and work my way from up to the bottom. When checking my layers they are arranged differently. The bottom duplicate is on top of the layers and visa versa.

Does anyone know how to change the duplicate layer option order? I want to make them down instead of going up the last layer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you duplicate your layers, but if you do it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, then it's definitely not too much of a burden to hold in that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and also press <kbd>[</kbd>. That will move it down a layer.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but if there is no answer that might be your most convenient alternative.