# How can I copy a layer a specified number of times?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I want to copy a layer 77 times. How can I do this quickly to avoid repetitive work?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21880/12189

Answer (score 1):

Manually copy the layer about 5 times. Then in the Layers pallet, multi-select your manually copied layers. Drag that stack of selected layers on to the "*Create a New Layer*" icon.

**Boom!** Now you have 10 duplicates and your original. Select the 11 layers and drag them on to the "*Create a New Layer*" icon.

**Boom!** now you have 22 duplicates. Do it again...

**Boom!** 33 duplicates. Again...

**Boom!** 44 dupes. And so on until you hit 77.

So, not completely automatic, but super fast once you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As per myknowledge there is no that kind of shortway in photoshop by giving count to duplicate layer.
There are different ways to duplicate the layers.
In that i prefer CTRL+J is the easiest way to duplicate the layer.

if i get this issue my i make some duplicates using CTRL+J and make a group.
i will duplicate that group.Atlost i ungroup layers